# How to solve this Q-Learning Algorithm question?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

[image: I can't solve this. I can't find any explanation, but I need it for my exam. Can someone help me point me in the right direction please? I don't need any answers, just to start somewhere.]

What I have so far, is this:

> **State 0**: A, A, B, B, C, C,
>
> **Direction**: left, right, left, right, left, right
>
> **State 1**: A, B, A, C, B, C
>
> **Initial value**: 0 0 0 0 0 0

So, as you can see, I have made a list before I get into the states. My next step is to do t1, which tells me to go from state A to the right...

When I put that in the formula, my teacher said to do:

> t1:Q(a,r) <-- 0 + 0.9 * max (0)
>
> **t1:Q(a,r) <-- 0**

**Question: what max is he talking about? The max of what?**

After step 1, he does step 2. This tells us:

> t2, from state B, move right. (reset)

So now, what he does, is:

> t2:Q(b,r) <-- 1 + 0.9 max * (0)

This is what I get, but I still don't know what the max is about...

And after he is finished, he gets this state:

> **State 0**: A, A, B, B, C, C,
>
> **Direction**: left, right, left, right, left, right
>
> **State 1**: A, B, A, C, B, C
>
> **Values**: 0 0.9 0 1 0 0

**I don't understand why he changes A,R to 0.9
And B,R to 1**

Can someone please explain me how I should do this? I couldn't find anything relevant on the net to solve this, that's why I am asking it here.

Comment: should this have the 'self study' tag?

Comment: Yeah, added that. I can see that the max function says: "take the max of the next action and all actions". What is the difference to be precise? Can someone help me please?

Comment: It usually takes a few hours for answers from people to flow in.  I think that you are getting lost in notation.  The "max" in epsilon-greedy q-learning is to take the best rewarding path of all the paths at least 1-epsilon percent of the time until learning has converged.

Comment: I solved it by my own btw; I get the formula now. Thanks.

Comment: @ Siyah, put the answer in.  If you have it, write it up.  It is a good question to ask, and others may value the answer.